# How to set an animated canvas as the background for a layout

Tags: java, android, layout, canvas

I'm making a simple app that has a Main Activity that I want to have little things flying across the screen. I still want to keep my LinearLayout xml file, but is there a way to programatically set the background to a movable canvas while keeping the layout on top?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with a LinearLayout, you want to stack other views on top of the canvas which cannot be done linearly.

You could always use a RelativeLayout to achieve what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can implement it using FrameLayout

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html

for example

```
<FrameLayout

    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_width="250dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="Frame Demo"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```